# iOS & Facebook Game integration questions (High level)

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

Is Facebook a viable platform for storing and sending object data?

Say I have an iOS game. Want to invite my Facebook friends to play. Does Facebook have the capability of storing my "invite to play" data, such that when a friend logs in on iOS, that data will be available? If so, can I store arbitrary data, maybe a dictionary?

Candy Crush does this but I'm not sure if this is handled on Candy Crush's backend or if it's through Facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Candy Crush does it through it's backend. Facebook surely stores all data that you want but i do not see any API from facebook allowing us to access it.

Comment: Cool. I noticed that when I get an invite in that game, it actually comes through Facebook and the Facebook push message system.